CSS rule for item that's not contained in a specific element
Suppose this interface. I would like to hide only the bbbbbb text and keep the aaaaaa. I thought that the rule seen in the code snippet would do the job but it doesn't. What am I missing?


.main-wrapper .element :not(.top-part) .our-guy {
  display: none;
}
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="top-part">
      <div class="our-guy">
        aaaaaa
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="our-guy">
      bbbbbbb
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




You can require that .top-part not be the immediate parent of .our-guy using the following syntax to hide bbbbbbb


.main-wrapper .element .our-guy:not(.top-part > *) {
  display: none;
}
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="top-part">
      <div class="our-guy">
        aaaaaa
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="our-guy">
      bbbbbbb
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Your code applies to neither of them because bbbbbb doesn't have a parent element, so there's nothing to match :not(.top-part). If you add such an element, your selector works


.main-wrapper .element .our-guy:not(.top-part > *) {
  display: none;
}
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="top-part">
      <div class="our-guy">
        aaaaaa
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="other-part">
      <div class="our-guy">
        bbbbbbb
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




I don't have access to the layout of the HTML, so part B of your answer is not even possible. But part A was gold!
